# Sort error - dates in Unity

Tags: c#, list, sorting, unity-game-engine

Here's an interesting one. I am sorting a list by date using the iComparable interface. I was testing it again today, when I noticed something. I had entered 11/1/2016 as a date. When the data was sent to the screen, that date was first even though the other dates in the list were before it. I realize that the system would think that 11 might need to be at the top of the list, but how can I fix this?

```
public class SortbyDate :IComparer<OilChange> {
  public int Compare(OilChange x, OilChange y) {
    return x.ServiceDate.CompareTo (y.ServiceDate);
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Strange. What is the type of the "OilChange.ServiceDate" property? It's really a DateTime or it's a string?

Comment: it is a String. DateTime had too many problems.

Comment: Well, this is the cause of the sorting problem. What problems did you have with DateTime?

Comment: I wasn't able to eliminate the time part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really recommend changing the type of the string variable to DateTime. It is WAY better to manipulate dates. However, if you want to stick with string for some reason, you could convert to date just in the time of sorting.

```
public class SortbyDate :IComparer<OilChange>
{
    public int Compare(OilChange x, OilChange y)
    {
        DateTime dateX = Convert.ToDateTime(x.ServiceDate);
        DateTime dateY = Convert.ToDateTime(y.ServiceDate);
        return dateX.CompareTo(dateY);
    }
}
```

If your problem is just formatting the date, try:

```
string date = String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", dateTimeValue);
```

Read more [here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/).

Comment: Thanks Guilherme! That worked! Thanks to Jonathan too!

Answer (score 1):

If you sort it as a string, 11 is going to come before, for example, 2, making November come before February. If the value that it represents is a date, you should probably store and manipulate it as a date.

Here are the functions I'm using for date swapping

```
public string SwitchDate(string date)
{
    Debug.Log ("Date IN: Switch " + date);
    string[] inputSections=date.Split('/');
    string ServiceDate=string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", inputSections[2], inputSections[0], inputSections[1]); 
    Debug.Log ("Date OUT: Switch " + ServiceDate);

    return ServiceDate;
}

string SwitchbackDate(string date)
{
    Debug.Log ("Switchback In: " +date);
    string[] inputSections=date.Split('/');
    string ServiceDate=string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}",inputSections[1], inputSections[2], inputSections[0]); 
    Debug.Log ("Switchback Out: " + ServiceDate);

    return ServiceDate;
}
```

Comment: What would be the best way to remove the extraneous information like the time, colons and the like?

Comment: when you output the date (in a grid, or label, or whatever), `ToString()` it with a date format. eg `myDate.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy")` see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings for more details

Comment: Worked beautifully!

Comment: I went back and added 11/1/xxxx to some old data and unfortunately, it pushed the date to the top again. Any thoughts?

Comment: how are you converting that 11/1/xxxx to a datetime object? If you use `DateTime.Parse` it may be reversing month and day. Better would be to `DateTime.ParseExact` with a date time format to enforce month/day order

Comment: I'm using two functions that take in the string, then format it. I put the code in your answer. Hard to get code in a comment

Comment: I can see your comment. It looks like you're still handling your dates as strings. As long as you do that, you're likely going to have issues. The only time that the values should be strings, is when they are being 'printed'; to the screen, on a report, etc. When they are processed or manipulated, that should be done as datetime objects.